# Error when installing Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, installation, bcd

When I try to install Windows 10 on my laptop I get an error stating that the installer is unable to move into the next step of installation and to restart my PC to install Windows. This happens repeatedly. Also the reason I am trying to reinstall is that I received an error code stating that the boot configuration data is missing or corrupted. I tried using bootrec /rebuildbcd but that did not work.

Comment: Check that if the installation media works. Delete the volume and remake/format it during installation.

Comment: My friend just used this installation usb about a week ago and had no problems. As far as formatting I did try that. However should I also format the system reserved partition and just merge the whole drive?

Comment: If you don't need any backup from that reserved partition you may delete and merge that. But do `NOT DELETE EFI SYSTEM PARTITION` if have.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by using diskpart to to set the partition as active. Im not exactly sure why it was not active in the first place and I wish I would have found out before formatting the drive X( but thankfully I did not have anything important in the disk. Thanks for the help.